# Is there a way to read a var passed and replace its value

Tags: variables, replace, properties, less, short

Is there a way to read a variable passed and replace its value.

### less

```
.mar(@B) when (default()) {
    margin:~'@{B}px';        
}
.mar(@A,@B){
    margin-@{A}:~'@{B}px';        
}
```

### usage

```
.foo1{
    .mar(3);
}
.foo2{
    .mar(t,3);
}
```

the **t** value passed would be replaced by the word **top** and so worth for other letters, b for bottom, etc...

I could pass the entire word *eg:top* but i'm trying to shorten the amount of text I type after the initial mixin.

Answer (score -1):

You can make four overloads of the mixin:

```
.mar(t, @B){
    margin-top: ~'@{B}px';        
}
.mar(b, @B){
    margin-bottom: ~'@{B}px';        
}
```

However, abbreviating code this way is not very readable.  Don't do this.